# Зачем "балансируют" дерево?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, дерево

Если есть возможность, то покажите пример на С#.

Comment: Для сбалансированного дерева, время доступа обычно log(n), для несбалансирвоанного стремиться к n. То есть, все элементы вытягиваются в одну ветку и вместо дерева получается список

Comment: чтобы быстрее работали операции определенные на этом дереве

Comment: А вдруг это описано в КАЖДОЙ книге по алгоритмам и структурам данных?

Comment: Причем чего показать?